# R and svyglm - how to get standard error for an odds ratio?

Tags: r

How do we get a standard error for an odds ratio obtained from output produced by the `svyglm()` function in the R package "survey"?

The model fitted with svyglm is of the form:

```
svyglm(Outcome ~ Treatment,design=design.object,family=quasibinomial(link=logit))
```

The odds ratio comparing the two levels of Treatment can be easily obtained by exponentiating the coefficients produced by the `summary()` command applied to the above model.

Not clear how to produce standard errors associated with this odds ratio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe something like: `predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(Treatment = mean(datasetname$Treatment)), se.fit = T)` - based on this page: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/deltamethod.htm and saving your `svyglm()` results to `fit`. I'm really guessing though as I'm not sure what your data/analysis exactly is.

Comment: You can use `confint()` on the model to get confidence intervals of the coefficients; the antilog of those are the confidence limits of the odds ratios. That isn't the same as standard errors, but it is one measure of uncertainty.

Comment: @BrianDiggs - probably simpler and more common. I thought I'd *try* to answer the question as is, but it might well make more sense to just use CI's.

Comment: Thank you very much - I already got the confidence interval for the odds ratio, but I was hoping to also get a standard error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your elderly question. If `model` is your svyglm output use:

`SE(model)`

Comment: The question was about SEs for the odds ratio, not for the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svycontrast` to get SEs for linear and nonlinear functions of a statistics, such as the odds ratio from `svyglm`

```
> data(api)
> dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
> model<-svyglm(sch.wide~ell+meals+mobility, design=dstrat,family=quasibinomial())
> coef(model)
 (Intercept)          ell        meals     mobility 
 0.835836525 -0.002489636 -0.003152365  0.060896779 
> exp(coef(model))
(Intercept)         ell       meals    mobility 
  2.3067429   0.9975135   0.9968526   1.0627892 
> 
> svycontrast(model, quote(exp(ell)))
           nlcon     SE
contrast 0.99751 0.0132
> SE(svycontrast(model, quote(exp(ell))))
  contrast 
0.01321955
```